# I am stuck on a quiz in Udacity for JavaScript on Multi-dimensional arrays.

Tags: javascript, arrays

The quiz is about a multidimensional array and wants us to use a nested for loop to cycle through each element and replace the values that are divisible by 2 with the strings 'even' and 'odd' for even and odd numbers respectively. I cannot print out the array with the numbers divisible by 2 on to the console with the added string.

I have tried using .slice() and .splice() also but that did not get me the desired results either. Below is my latest attempt.

Programming Quiz - Multi-dimensional Arrays:
Question: Use a nested for loop to take the numbers array below and replace all of the values that are divisible by 2 (even numbers) with the string "even" and all other numbers with the string "odd".

```
var numbers = [
[243, 12, 23, 12, 45, 45, 78, 66, 223, 3],
[34, 2, 1, 553, 23, 4, 66, 23, 4, 55],
[67, 56, 45, 553, 44, 55, 5, 428, 452, 3],
[12, 31, 55, 445, 79, 44, 674, 224, 4, 21],
[4, 2, 3, 52, 13, 51, 44, 1, 67, 5],
[5, 65, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 43, 23, 4424],
[74, 532, 6, 7, 35, 17, 89, 43, 43, 66],
[53, 6, 89, 10, 23, 52, 111, 44, 109, 80],
[67, 6, 53, 537, 2, 168, 16, 2, 1, 8],
[76, 7, 9, 6, 3, 73, 77, 100, 56, 100]
];
```

My code:
//create a nested for loop to cycle through each row and column

```
for(let row = 0; row < numbers.length; row++){
    for(let col = 0; col < numbers.length; col++){
```

//if the even numbers in each row and column are divisible by 2, replace those
//numbers with the word even

```
    if(numbers % 2 === 0){
        numbers[row] += 'even';
        }
    }
}
console.log(numbers);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're real close! It comes down to how you're referencing the index in the 2-dimensional array. Iterating over it in a nested for loop requires first that we iterate through the rows, then the columns. In your example, you were actually iterating over the columns twice. In order to fix this, you would simply iterate over the `row` index of the numbers array in the nested for loop:

```
    for(let row = 0; row < numbers.length; row++){
        for(let col = 0; col < numbers[row].length; col++){
```

Then finally you will need to set the target index `numbers[row][col]` to even. In your example you used the addition assignment operator `+=`, which performs what is string concatenation. Instead of simply changing the index value to 'even', the `+=` would actually add the word 'even' to the end of the number. So the index output would actually read something like `156even`. Just drop the plus sign in order to reassign the index to `even`:

```
numbers[row][col] = 'even';
```

```js
    var numbers = [
    [243, 12, 23, 12, 45, 45, 78, 66, 223, 3], 
    [34, 2, 1, 553, 23, 4, 66, 23, 4, 55],
    [67, 56, 45, 553, 44, 55, 5, 428, 452, 3],
    [12, 31, 55, 445, 79, 44, 674, 224, 4, 21],
    [4, 2, 3, 52, 13, 51, 44, 1, 67, 5],
    [5, 65, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 43, 23, 4424],
    [74, 532, 6, 7, 35, 17, 89, 43, 43, 66],
    [53, 6, 89, 10, 23, 52, 111, 44, 109, 80],
    [67, 6, 53, 537, 2, 168, 16, 2, 1, 8],
    [76, 7, 9, 6, 3, 73, 77, 100, 56, 100]
    ];

for(let row = 0; row < numbers.length; row++){
    for(let col = 0; col < numbers[row].length; col++){    //iterate over the n-th index of numbers[]
        if(numbers[row][col] % 2 === 0){    //numbers[row][col] points to the nested index
            numbers[row][col] = 'even';    //set index to 'even'
        }
    }
}

console.log(numbers);
```

This video is a nice explanation of how iterating over 2d arrays works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qdT1P2qmsmU

The video is using Java, but the idea is exactly the same.

Hope this helps! Multi-dimensional arrays are tough to wrap your brain around!

Comment: This worked great! and you explained in a way that was easy to understand. Thank you! Also, the video link is very helpful. I'm going to watch more videos from this guy.